# Defining common symbology across multiple geometry types

Tags: symbology, qgis-2.14

I have two layers in QGIS; one points and one simple lines. Each have an attribute, `community`, which I'd like to serve as the category variable for assigning color. But I can't figure out any way to make these color-variable assignments identical between the two layers. I can't copy/paste styles, nor can I export a QML and apply it to the other layer, because of their different `GeometryType`.

Is there any way to do this short of exporting two QML files, one for each layer, and writing some sort of Python script to interchange the `<prop k="color" v=" ... "/>` in the points style definition, and           `<prop k="line_color" v=" ... "/>` in the lines style definition?

The `community` variable in both layers has >50 possible values, so it's too cumbersome to do this by hand.

Comment: Try creating a simple 1 or 2 classification QML for both line and point layer and open them up with a text editor.  There may be a tag in there that defines the geometry type which you might be able to do a find and replace on to switch the geometry so you do not have to spend time created the full QML for both layer geom types.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if anyone has better ideas on how to solve this, but here's one workaround which I found worked OK:

- Create a new CSV file with two columns, `community` and `color`
- Write in 50 `community, color` pairs into that CSV, using `"r,g,b"` as the color format. (I used [this](http://phrogz.net/css/distinct-colors.html) online color generator to auto-generate 50 distinct colors.)
- Import that CSV into QGIS as an attribute-only layer
- Join that new layer to both my points layer and my lines layer using the `community` field as the join
- In each geometry layer, use the newly-joined `color` field as a data-defined variable for either point color or line color